# The PDAL filter.crop does not work if using the USER CRS (not EPSG)

Tags: qgis, python, coordinate-system, pdal

I use pdal (in my own QGIS plugin) to create a raster dem from the cloud of points (*.las).
I have points data in the EPSG CRS and there is data in the user defined CRS.
Everything works fine, I get DEM.
I also use crop in area of interest and if the points and the area in the EPSG CRS, then I get a cropped DEM.

But when I add an area of interest to crop in the user defined CRS (both - crop polygon and points):

```
File "libpdalpython.pyx", line 180, in pdal.libpdalpython.PyPipeline.execut 
RuntimeError: filters.crop: Geometry::transform() failed.  NULL source SRS.
```

I also used the parameter [a_srs](https://pdal.io/stages/filters.crop.html#filters-crop), it did not help.

Does PDAL support user defined CRS for cropping filter?

PDAL 2.2.0?, QGIS 3.18 Python 3.8

PDAL pipeline dump:

> ['C:\Users\User\Desktop\test_data\result\995-290_relief.las',
> {'type': 'readers.las', 'filename':
> 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\test_data\result\995-290_relief.las',
> 'override_srs':
> 'PROJCS["MSK-38z3",GEOGCS["GCS_Krassovsky_1942",DATUM["D_unknown",SPHEROID["krass",6378245,298.3]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",103.03333333333],PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],PARAMETER["false_easting",3250000],PARAMETER["false_northing",-5411057.63],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]'},
> {'type': 'filters.assign', 'value': ['NumberOfReturns = 1 WHERE
> (NumberOfReturns == 0)', 'ReturnNumber = 1 WHERE (ReturnNumber ==
> 0)']}, {'type': 'filters.crop', 'a_srs':
> 'PROJCS["MSK-38z3",GEOGCS["GCS_Krassovsky_1942",DATUM["D_unknown",SPHEROID["krass",6378245,298.3]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",103.03333333333],PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],PARAMETER["false_easting",3250000],PARAMETER["false_northing",-5411057.63],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]',
> 'polygon': {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[(3329165.9740588237,
> 299685.50776470604), (3329485.954764706, 299690.4687058825), (3329488.781596312, 299508.1380673197), (3329168.8008904294,
> 299503.17712614324), (3329165.9740588237, 299685.50776470604)]]}}, {'type': 'filters.assign', 'value': ['Classification = 1 WHERE
> Classification != 2']}, {'type': 'writers.las', 'filename':
> 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\test_data\result\995-290_relief_ground.las'},
> {'type': 'filters.range', 'limits': 'Classification[2:2]'}, {'type':
> 'filters.elm'}, {'type': 'filters.outlier'}, {'type':
> 'filters.sample', 'radius': 5.0}, {'filename':
> 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\test_data\result\995-290_relief_dem.tif',
> 'gdaldriver': 'GTiff', 'resolution': 5.0, 'output_type': 'mean',
> 'type': 'writers.gdal', 'data_type': 'float32'}]

Comment: What are the exact CRS' involved here?

Comment: PROJCS["MSK-38z3",GEOGCS["GCS_Krassovsky_1942",DATUM["D_unknown",SPHEROID["krass",6378245.0,298.3]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",3250000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",-5411057.63],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",103.03333333333],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.0],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]